# Which database(s) should I use for predominantly Write once/Read Many operations?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, non-relational-database

I'm building an application that needs to query a lot of data that is written once and not changed anymore. Should I use MySQL for that or should I use something like SimpleDB or BigTable? (I need to write once, read many times)

Thank you.

Edit: I want to use Heroku, big for me is more than 5MB. "Thousands of rows" take more than 5MB. That's why I'm wondering if I should use CouchDB, SimpleDB or MongoDB in order not to pay the $15 that Heroku charges. Suggestions to overcome this? Thank you all for the comments!

Comment: Do you want to do joins?  Do you want to retrieve data by attributes other than UID?  How important is performance?  By "lots of data" do you mean big sets of many rows or many reads of single rows?

Comment: What are your performance/durability expectations? Sharding?

Comment: You forgot the most important information: the shape of your data. If your data is not relational, then MySQL is out of the question anyway, regardless of what your perfomance requirements are. And if your data *is* relational, then SimpleDB and BigTable are out of the question. Do you have relational data? Graph data? Semi-structured document data? Hierarchical data? Ontology/Triple/RDF data? And I also agree with @FractalizeR: do you need A, C, I, D? If yes, how much or how little of each do you need? When do you need it? Are the needs always the same or do they differ from query to query?

Comment: "lots of data" = Thousands of rows that can be read many many times at a time. The data is relational. Edit: I'll have a table with thousands of references to S3 files and each user will be able to create a "portfolio" of those files. So each user will have unlimited files in his portfolio.

Comment: Thousands of rows = small amount of data. So, any DB is ok, I think. If you say millions, then you need to choose carefully.

Comment: "each user will have unlimited files" - I think you may have a storage problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More important than your choice of database engine is your table structure. You should read up on OLAP database structure. Another consideration is the language you are writing in, make sure there is good support for the API of the database you want to use. CouchDB would be good as it has very low overheads due to the lack of relations/transactions.

Comment: Since you're not using writes during operation, it doesn't matter how efficient it is at doing no writes :-). However due to the fact it does not do transactions, or manage relations, there is less overhead compared to other, more complex database systems like MySQL. It's about as simple as it gets, and that's a good thing in this case.

Comment: Do not pay for a database system to manage a 5MB database (small!). Use CouchDB and be done with it, or frankly use anything, you won't notice the difference. Have a read of this, the quotes in particular:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: Thank you! CouchDB for everything is fine? Even for storing usernames/passwords? I'll definitely think about it!

Comment: Yes it's fine. You should not be storing plaintext passwords, but cryptographic hashes:

http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp

Answer (score 4):

What does it mean "a lot of data"? Thousands, millions, billions of rows? How many and what columns per row? Will you use many joins or simple selects?

If your tables are simple or you need to use complicated JOINs, I would pick any SQL you're familiar with.

If your structure is complicated and if document oriented database would suit your needs, I would pick MongoDB (preferred) or CouchDB.

**Edit:** According to your comment - thousands of rows is not that much. Use your favourite database and set as much cache as it needs (read more about necessary cache amount or start a new topic). Or use Memcached but I suggest to use database cache as it's efficient too and painless for you. Goog luck man!

Comment: Thousands of rows. 20 columns per row. Thanks.

Comment: That's not even close to being big. Seriously. Any database engine will suit your need. Even free database engine.

Comment: @Tiago: If you want to use http://heroku.com/ as a web hosting and they charge $15 per database, then just make your decision and pay the fee or pick another hosting. It's absolutely normal that services (like hosting) cost money.

Comment: They offer 5MB for FREE and 1GB CouchDB for FREE.

Comment: @Tiago: You should pick the right technology according to your needs, the budget is not that important especially in your case - 15 bucks a month is a price of couple of burgers. Or if you want me to say - go for the 1GB FREE CouchDB, if this will make you happy, go for it!

Comment: @dwich - $15 is some money for me (I'm not in the US). Do you think that a 5MB database will handle thousands of rows? (~100k) ?

Comment: @Tiago: I'm not in the US either. Simple answer - try it for yourself on local computer first, test it, check the database size and then you'll see if the data fit in 5MB or not. No one here can tell you if your data will fit in 5MB. For your information if you expect ~100k rows, it's 500 bytes per row.

And again - pick the right technology you need, then find a hosting. Not in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

For "write once, read many times", de-normalized database (that does not waste cycles to do joins etc.) is a good choice.

So, you should design your tables such that these reads have to do minimum number of I/Os and joins. You can do that with any database. It is the structure of your tables that matters.

AFAIK, SimpleDB and BigTable are distributed databases and offer very good query speeds if your users are distributed geographically (thereby bypassing the network latencies). They will not offer much advantage if the I/O latency is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data you have is tiny. Any DBMS will cope with a few thousand rows. I suggest you look first at one of the popular SQL DBMSs - such as MySQL, which you already mentioned. You need to make the choice based on the functional requirements rather than be concerned with the data size.

Answer (score 0):

A separate database is overkill for this kind of small scale use case. Just serialise your data into a flat file and then read it in to the map data structure of choice in your language.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use non transactional and document oriented  database like MongoDB or CouchDB .

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?